# How to add element into an array from a variable in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

```
declare
type id_no is varray(10) of number;
p_where id_no:=id_no();
begin
go_block('employees');
first_record;
loop
if checkbox_checked('checkbox') then
```

I want how many `emp_id` I will select
     exact number of selected emp_id will store in p_where() array

```
p_where()=:employees.empi_id;
end if;
exit when :system.last_record='TRUE';
next_record;
end loop;
```

exact number of selected emp_id will store in :emp_id column

```
for i in 1..p_where.count loop
    :empi_id:=p_where(i);
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a variable to complicate things? `IdArray id_no :=  id_no(10,1,20,50,100,5000,70 );` simply works

Comment: v_element variable contains checkbox checked values which will store in a same number of row of a column  that i can't into the array variable

Comment: But, a `varchar2`  variable can't contain multiple values. Please elaborate on "*..contains checkbox checked values..*"  It's not at all clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: declare
 v_count     number;
 type in_no is varray(100) of number;

Comment: declare
type id_no is varray(10) of number;
p_where id_no:=id_no();
begin
go_block('employees');
first_record;
loop
if checkbox_checked('checkbox') then
--i want how many emp_id i will select
--exact number of selected emp_id will store in p_where() array
p_where()=:employees.empi_id;
end if;
exit when :system.last_record='TRUE';
next_record;
end loop;
--exact number of selected emp_id will store in :emp_id column
for i in 1..p_where.count loop
 :empi_id:=p_where(i);
end loop;
end;

Comment: Are you using Oracle Forms?

Comment: Out of interest, why `varray` instead of the standard nested table which has more functionality?

Comment: yah oracle forms 10g